# Error installing Sass (Ruby 2.5.0.1, MSYS2 20161025.0.0)

Tags: ruby, sass, ffi, msys2, chocolatey

I tried to install Sass. I installed *Ruby* and *MSYS2* prior to that, the latest from all with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/):

```
choco install ruby
choco install msys2
```

Seemingly they were properly installed. `ruby -v` results in:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x64-mingw32]
```

When I tried to run `gem install sass` I received the following error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
        The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

Ok, so I attempted to run `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18`.

I received this error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        The last version of ffi (= 1.9.18) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18`
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

I tried to reinstall Ruby with proper installer, restarted computer, but the same error appears.

*How can I make Sass to get installed?*

Comment: Looks like `ffi` doesn't support 2.5 yet. Downgrade to 2.4?

Comment: Looks like you are right @cremno as downgrading to Ruby v2.4.3.1 made it work. Yesterday I already installed it but did not work. Today I made sure I removed all instances of Ruby and then installing v2.4.3.1 and msys2, allowed to install Sass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install the Ruby version before 2.5 (as mentioned in the comments):

```
choco install ruby --version 2.4.3.1
```

Comment: Works great! but I had to include the `--allow-downgrade` flag as well