# Error on installing SASS on WIndows 10 and ruby version 2.5.0-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rubygems

I have tried to install Sass in Windows 10 with `Ruby version 2.5.0-1` but i'm getting following error:

> ERROR:  Error installing sass:
>           The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
>           ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.

Windows 10
Ruby Installer - 2.5.0-1 (64 bit)
Gem version - 2.7.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Install gem ffi - Windows 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171022/cannot-install-gem-ffi-windows-7-64bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffi doesn't support 2.5 yet. Downgrade to 2.4.

Source: [Error installing sass (Ruby 2.5.0.1, MSYS2 20161025.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142031/error-installing-sass-ruby-2-5-0-1-msys2-20161025-0-0)